# How to add Run Time Tabs into TabHost in Android?

Tags: android, layout, tabs, android-tabhost

Hello I am developing an application
Which requires to add Run Time tabs in the android And all the tabs should add dynamically.

My Requirement is:

- I want to add Tabhost with 5 tabs Which Should display the Screen.
- But some Time it require only 3 tabs in the screen then design should not change.
- Same if I want to add more then 5 tabs then tab should scroll Run time The main Thing is Design should not change.

Can any one tell me How can i do that?

Currently I am using Following Code:

```
 public class Story_List extends ActivityGroup  
    {
            ListView list_stories;
            TabHost tab_stories;

            @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
            {
                requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
                super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                setContentView(R.layout.story_list);

                tab_stories=(TabHost)findViewById(R.id.tabhoststories);
                tab_stories.setup(this.getLocalActivityManager());

                setupTab1(new TextView(this), "Album 1");
                setupTab2(new TextView(this), "Album 2");
                setupTab3(new TextView(this), "Album 3");
            }

            private void setupTab1(final View view, final String tag) 
            {

                View tabview = createTabView(tab_stories.getContext(), tag);

                Intent intent = new Intent().setClass(this, StoryAlbum1.class);
                TabSpec tab = tab_stories.newTabSpec(tag).setIndicator(tabview).setContent(intent);
                tab_stories.addTab(tab);
            }
            private void setupTab2(final View view, final String tag) 
            {

                View tabview = createTabView(tab_stories.getContext(), tag);

                Intent intent = new Intent().setClass(this, StoryAlbum2.class);
                TabSpec tab = tab_stories.newTabSpec(tag).setIndicator(tabview).setContent(intent);
                tab_stories.addTab(tab);
            }
            private void setupTab3(final View view, final String tag) 
            {

                View tabview = createTabView(tab_stories.getContext(), tag);

                Intent intent = new Intent().setClass(this, StoryAlbum3.class);
                TabSpec tab = tab_stories.newTabSpec(tag).setIndicator(tabview).setContent(intent);
                tab_stories.addTab(tab);
            }

            private static View createTabView(final Context context, final String text) 
            {
                View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.tabs_text, null);
                TextView tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tabsText);
                tv.setText(text);
                return view;
            }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
TabHost.TabSpec tabSpec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab1");
    tabSpec.setContent(R.id.btnTab);
    tabSpec.setIndicator("My Tab 1");
    tabHost.addTab(tabSpec);
    btnAddTab.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            TabHost.TabSpec spec = tabHost.newTabSpec("Tab"+i);
            spec.setContent(new TabHost.TabContentFactory() {
                @Override
                public View createTabContent(String tag) {
                    return new AnalogClock(MainActivity.this);
                }
            });
            spec.setIndicator("Clock");
            tabHost.addTab(spec);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Can You tell me what is AnalogClock?

Comment: its just android build in class to set view in new created tab.

Comment: then remove it. and return any view (eg. return new TextView(MainActivity.this));